# RoboGuice inject different SharedPreferences

Tags: android, android-studio, dependency-injection, guice, roboguice

In `RoboGuice` when I'm using:

```
@Inject
SharedPreferences prefs;
```

It injects the default `SharedPreferences` 
How do I inject **not default** preferences?
like `context.getSharedPreferences("my_prefs", Context.MODE_PRIVATE)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From `Roboguice` documentation:

> #### Shared Preferences
>
> **Class:** SharedPreferences
>
> **Provider:** SharedPreferencesProvider
>
> **Scope:** Transient Injection
>
> **Points:** Constructors, Fields, Methods By default
>
> roboguice will retrieve an instance of Android SharedPreferences using
>   the filename: "default". This is not the default file name android
>   uses for your shared preferences. If you would like to override the
>   file name then you can set up a binding when RoboGuice is initialized.
>
> Android Default Shared Preferences File Name Binding
>
> ```
> bindConstant()
>     .annotatedWith(SharedPreferencesName.class)
>     .to("com.mypackage.myapp_preferences");
> ```
>
> Example
>
> ```
> public class MyActivity extends RoboActivity {
>   @Inject SharedPreferences sharedPreferences;
> }
> ```
>
> Provider Example
>
> ```
> public class MyActivity extends RoboActivity {
>   @Inject Provider<SharedPreferences> sharedPreferencesrProvider;
> }
> ```
>
> From: https://github.com/roboguice/roboguice/wiki/Provided-Injections

I haven't used `RoboGuice` before, but I'm pretty sure that:

```
@Inject
SharedPreferences prefs;
```

means the same as:

```
SharedPreferences prefs = getActivity().getPreferences(Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
```

so if you want to get a key value, you would use only:

```
int highScore = prefs.getInt("my_prefs", defaultValue);
```

and to put a new value:

```
editor.putInt("my_prefs", newHighScore);
```

Hope it will help